# EC2InstanceMetadata.IAMSecurityCredentials is null

Tags: amazon-ec2, metadata, aws-security-group

Until yesterday I was successfully getting the IAM Security Credentials in a .net application using:

```
var securtiyCredentials = EC2InstanceMetadata.IAMSecurityCredentials;
```

But now it's returning a null for that call.

A curl of the service is timing out when I try it in powershell:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

However when I navigate in a browser to:

```
http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

It returns the following list (notice that IAMSecurityCredentials is missing):

```
ami-id
ami-launch-index
ami-manifest-path
block-device-mapping/
hostname
iam/
instance-action
instance-id
instance-type
local-hostname
local-ipv4
mac
metrics/
network/
placement/
profile
public-keys/
reservation-id
security-groups
services/
```

Any idea what could have cause the IAMSecurityCredentials from not being returned?

Answer (score 0):

The proxy's on the effected EC2 box was changed to resolve a different issue inadvertently causing the problem posted here.